# Where to put the Change Event Code

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

CHANGE EVENT: I have 12 sheets in a workbook. Do you have to put the Change Event in the 12 sheet, if not, where I must put the code for this event.

Comment: It will depend upon what you want to accomplish. If it is pretty muchy the same operation for all 12 worksheets, use a `Workbook_SheetChange` in *ThisWorkbook* and deal with *Sh* as the worksheet. If the operations are individual for each (or only a few) then individual `Worksheet_Change` for each sheet code page may be more appropriate. If you provided some details, further recommendations might be forthcoming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to occur on any of the sheets, you must use a [workbook_sheetchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196611(v=office.15).aspx) event. This goes in `ThisWorkbook` module.

For it to affect only specific sheets, you must use [worksheet_change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775%28v=office.15%29.aspx). This goes in each `sheet` module of each sheet that you want affected.